# Method orderby/group by/having not found in query jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

I'm new to jOOQ and I have to translate a query into jOOQ;

My table "CN_THEODOINO" include two fields: NAM (means YEAR) and THANG (means MONTH) with the data types are short and byte.

I want to calculate the different months between the sysdate and the NAM and THANG in that table.

After that, I will compare with the p_diff from my parameter and select those greater than it.

I try this:

```
public List<CN_DS_NO> layDsKHangNo3(String sInputParam) throws JSONException {
    try {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int currMonths = c.get(Calendar.YEAR) * 12 + c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(sInputParam);
        short p_diff    =    (short)jsonObj.getInt("SO_THANGNO");
        Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
        condition = condition.and(bangDsChuyenNo2.TIEN_NO.gt(Long.valueOf(0)));
        condition = condition.and(bangDsChuyenNo2.NAM.mul(12).add(bangDsChuyenNo2.THANG).add(p_diff).sub(currMonths).lessOrEqual((short)0));
        condition = condition.groupBy(bangDsChuyenNo2.MA_KHANG);
        condition = condition.having(DSL.count(bangDsChuyenNo2.ID_HDON).gt(jsonObj.getInt("SO_HOADON")).and(DSL.sum((Field) field(bangDsChuyenNo2.TIEN_NO)).gt(jsonObj.getLong("TONG_NO"))));

        qDsChuyenNo = this.getCreate()
                        .select()
                        .from(bangDsChuyenNo)
                        .where(condition);
        return nativeQuery(this.getEm(), qDsChuyenNo, CN_DS_NO.class);

            } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
            }
```

I get two errors, say:

Error(141,34): cannot find symbol;  symbol:   method groupBy(org.jooq.TableField);  location: variable condition of type org.jooq.Condition

Error(142,34): cannot find symbol;  symbol:   method having(org.jooq.Condition);  location: variable condition of type org.jooq.Condition

So how can I do this in jOOQ. I've already searched in google and our forum but couldn't get the answer. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The [`org.jooq.Condition`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html) type models a SQL predicate. It has methods to combine predicates using [`AND`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html#and-org.jooq.Condition-) and [`OR`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Condition.html#or-org.jooq.Condition-) operators, but certainly no methods that belong in the `SELECT` query, such as `GROUP BY` or `HAVING`. Just move those clauses to where they belong:

```java
Condition condition = DSL.trueCondition();
condition = condition.and(bangDsChuyenNo2.TIEN_NO.gt(Long.valueOf(0)));
condition = condition.and(bangDsChuyenNo2.NAM.mul(12).add(bangDsChuyenNo2.THANG).add(p_diff).minus(currMonths).greaterThan((short)0));

// These calls make no sense at this position:
// condition = condition.groupBy(bangDsChuyenNo2.MA_KHANG);
// condition = condition.having(DSL.count(bangDsChuyenNo2.ID_HDON).gt(jsonObj.getInt("SO_HOADON")).and(DSL.sum((Field) field(bangDsChuyenNo2.TIEN_NO)).gt(jsonObj.getLong("TONG_NO"))));

qDsChuyenNo = this.getCreate()
                  .select()
                  .from(bangDsChuyenNo)
                  .where(condition)

                  // Above clauses moved down here:
                  .groupBy(bangDsChuyenNo2.MA_KHANG)
                  .having(DSL.count(bangDsChuyenNo2.ID_HDON)
                             .gt(jsonObj.getInt("SO_HOADON"))
                             .and(DSL.sum((Field) field(bangDsChuyenNo2.TIEN_NO))
                             .gt(jsonObj.getLong("TONG_NO"))))
                  ;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight, Lukas.I have one more question. Do I have to write bangDsChuyenNo2.NAM.mul(12).add(bangDsChuyenNo2.THANG).add(p_diff).minus(currMonths) which mean bangDsChuyenNo2.NAM + bangDsChuyenNo2.THANG + p_diff - currMonths instead of currMonths - p_diff - bangDsChuyenNo2.NAM * 12 - bangDsChuyenNo2.THANG. It seems like the second one is more nature (to me)?

Comment: Please, @NghịLê: Can you ask a new question? Stack Overflow will not run out of question IDs any time soon. It's hard to answer questions in these comments...